# laravel routes, how to group similar in one file

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

I'm working with `laravel`(5.2), and there are a lot routes in my route file.

in fresh install I noticed that it was loading `auth` routes something like this.

```
Route::auth();
```

nothing else was there in `routes.php` file related to `auth` routes.

in my file, I've like this one

```
Route::get('color/event', 'ColorController@index');
Route::post('color/event', 'ColorController@post_message);
...
...
```

and many others, So I want to load all in `laravel` way, like `Route::color();` and it should load all color related `routes`

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, anyone if s/he is looking for same answer, I figured that out.

if you want something like `Route::auth();` OR `Route::color();//in my case` or whatever you want to call it, you need to add custom `function` in your `Router.php` file. So solution will look like

```
//inside Router.php file
public function whatever(){
    $this->get('app/', 'AppController@index');
    $this->post('app/new', 'AppController@create');
}
```

and in your `route.php` file, you can do this.

```
Route::whatever();
```

***But this is really dirty way to do that***

so instead you can extend the base `Router` and register your router in **`bootstrap/app.php`**

```
$app->singleton('router', 'App\Your\Router');
```

so I community forces to use second approach.

for more details, have a look here.

- [Extending Router(laravel.io forum)](http://laravel.io/forum/02-12-2015-l5-extending-router)
- [Extending default Laravel 5 Router](http://blog.lanin.me/extending-default-laravel-router/)
- [How to extend Router or Replace Customer Router class on Laravel5?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/can-i-find-the-way-to-extend-router-or-replace-customer-router-class-on-laravel5)

hope someone will find this useful

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
Route::resource('admin/settings','Admin\SettingsController');
```

and try this command

```
$ php artisan routes
```

Comment: yes, true, but this will function like store edit in controller, but I want to map it on my own functions, and for each request there could be more than two functions, like for get request there will be two functions a and b,then in that case?

also what about `Route::Color()`, how can we do that?

Comment: Ohh sorry but i Have also don't have any idea related this kind. i have also find the solutions for this

Comment: I'm already doing it that way, I know this thing, but I want more shorty way in my `routes.php` file

Answer (score 0):

Using **Route::get()**, **Route::post()** and similar functions is **doing it the Laravel way** - see the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#basic-routing

**Route::auth()** is just a helper function introduced in **Laravel 5.2** to keep all auth definitions together.

Comment: can I create helper for my routes?